# Cakephp 3.6.14: Create table form with checkboxes and process data

Tags: php, arrays, forms, cakephp, checkbox

I want to create a form where there is an array with a checkbox for each row. So the user can select which rows will be processed in the controller.

So I have created the form and the array. Each row of the array has the name of the `Task Element` and a checkbox to select it:

[image]

```
<h3><?= __('Task Elements') ?></h3>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('AddElement', ['url'=>['action' => 'add',$tasktypeid]]); ?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('name') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('element_category_id') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>      
        <?php foreach ($taskElements as $taskElement): ?>      
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($taskElement->id) ?></td>
            <?= $this->Form->hidden('id',['value' => $taskElement->id]); ?>
            <td><?= $this->Form->control(h($taskElement->name), ['type' => 'checkbox']);?></td>
            <td><?= $taskElement->element_category_id != 0 ? $this->Html->link($taskElement->element_category->name, ['controller' => 'ElementCategories', 'action' => 'view', $taskElement->element_category->id]) : '' ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>            
    </tbody>
</table><?php
echo $this->Form->submit('Add');
echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

But in the controller `debug($this->request->getData());` returns this:

```
[
'id' => '32',
'Library_Element' => '0',
'Library_Element_2' => '0'
]
```

Which is not correct because 'Library_Element' id is 27 not 32. So it should return an array with 2 rows not an array with 1 row and 3 columns.

This is the correct array I am expecting to receive:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [Library_Element] => '0'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [Library_Element_2] => '0'
        )
)
```

Or ideally I would like to get an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [name] => 'Library Element'
            [checked] => '0'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [name] => 'Library Element 2'
            [checked] => '0'
        )
)
```

How I can fix that? And then in the controller I want to iterate the POST data and check for each row if it is checked or not. How I can correctly iterate the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing because when your webapp `POST`s to the backend, it will only send "form" data.

This means that whatever data you need to send back, you need to include within html `form` tags using form elements (i.e.: input, select, hidden, etc.). In a Cakephp template you would use the `Form` helper to print out these elements.

In this concrete case, you are creating a hidden `id` element and a checkbox element. Checkbox elements get their value from the fact that they are checked or not, and this value is 1 or 0... which seems right from what you are experiencing.

Please, tell us how you need the `POST`ed data to look like, so we can provide a better answer.

Some more generic advice on going to the root of things:

- Try to look at the generated html in your client (browser, view source)
- Use your browser's inspector (or dev tools) to introspect the network calls and see what data is `POST`ed to the backend

**EDIT**:

When your form is bound to an entity, this entity needs to be provided as the first argument to the `$this->Form->create($entity, ...)` call. In your case you are providing a string, not an entity.

Have a look at the docs for saving associated data in forms: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data

```
<tbody>      
    <?php foreach ($taskElements as $id => $taskElement): ?>      
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($taskElement->id) ?></td>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden("task.$id.id",['value' => $taskElement->id]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden("task.$id.name",['value' => $taskElement->name]); ?>
        <td><?= $this->Form->control("task.$id.checked", ['type' => 'checkbox']);?></td>
        <td><?= $taskElement->element_category_id != 0 ? $this->Html->link($taskElement->element_category->name, ['controller' => 'ElementCategories', 'action' => 'view', $taskElement->element_category->id]) : '' ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>            
</tbody>
```

Comment: please check the updated question with the correct return data format

Comment: I thinks this is what you need ^^